# Oracle SQL: Massive update of multiple rows (also repeated rows)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a tableX with two columns, some with repeated values like:

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| '1000 -- Some Text' | '2000 -- Some Text' |
| '1000 -- Some Text' | '2000 -- Some Text' |
| '1001 -- Some Text' | '2001 -- Some Text' |
| '1002 -- Some Text' | '2002 -- Some Text' |

What i want to do is to update both columns and remain with only the digits part:

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2000 |
| 1000 | 2000 |
| 1001 | 2001 |
| 1002 | 2002 |

I thinked in this possibility(for only one column):

```
update tableX
   set column1 = (
       select regexp_replace(column1, '[^0-9]', '')
         from tableX);
```

But this code gives me **ORA-01427**

What's the other way to do this update?

Comment: Apart from the problem, the last argument `''` provided for `regexp_replace()` is redundant to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
update tableX
   set column1 = regexp_replace(column1, '[^0-9]', '');
```

The  ORA-01427 is caused because the query

```
       select regexp_replace(column1, '[^0-9]', '')
         from tableX
```

returns all rows from tableX.